# Is there a way of checking the SA used in a Google API Gateway?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, gcloud, google-iam, google-cloud-api-gateway

I create an Google API Gateway recently with Terraform to create it associated with a custom SA that will handle the IAM between the backends and the API.

Now that's created I can't find a way to validate the creation using the Google Cloud Console, is there a way of validate this info by using gclou or other option?

Answer (score 1):

```
gcloud api-gateway api-configs describe my-config \
  --api=my-api --project=my-project
```

https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/secure-traffic-gcloud